# Is fb:app_id still required?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, seo, meta-tags

In [FACEBOOK for Developers docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup), `fb:app_id` is listed as one of **Basic Tags**:

> In order to use [Facebook Insights](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/966883707418907) you must add the app ID to your
> page.

But when I go to this link, they say that Facebook Analytics tool is no longer available as of July 1, 2021. Does that mean we no longer have to specify `fb:app_id` in meta tags in order to have our website preview?

Comment: This is about Insights, it has little to do with Open Graph previews.